# AngularFire, how to show name/email on page through uid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

As the topic says, how do I print it out on the page?
A LOT of the other topics regarding this are using SimpleLogin which is now deprecated so not much use of it, therefor another thread..

I have a registration function (name+email+password) and a login function (email+password) and when authenticated I want the page to print "Welcome {{user.name}}" for example. 
I feel like it's a really basic task but I can't get through it. When authed and redirected to dashboard.html (some problems with the routing there but that's another post, hint hint) - it only prints out the uid.

It looks something like this:

```
app.controller('dashController', ['currentAuth', '$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseAuth', '$rootScope', 'Auth', '$location',
  function(currentAuth, $scope, $firebaseArray, $firebaseAuth, $rootScope, Auth, $location){
    var ref = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com');
    $scope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
    $scope.user = $firebaseArray(ref);


    var authData = $scope.auth.$getAuth();

    $scope.id = authData.uid;
}]);
```

And html:

```
<span>Welcome {{id}}</span>
```

All the uid's are stored in /users/uid/name+email+pass.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
$scope.user = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

Your database isn't an array, so trying to bind it to the scope as an array is not helping anyone.

More likely you want to bind the specific user's profile data to the scope with:

```
$scope.user = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(authData.uid));
```

And then in your view:

```
<span>Welcome {{user.name}}</span>
```

I recommend that you follow the [AngularFire programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/) from start to finish. Doing so should for example make the difference between `$firebaseArray()` and `$firebaseObject()` clearer.

Comment: Edited out the previous message.
Anyway, that helped! Got an error at first but that was as simple as trying to fetch the data before it was defined.
Seems like you're good at Angular+Firebase, I'd love some help in my other thread if you'd like to assist. 
Marking this as the right answer! :)